# "service varnish stop" doesn't actually stop Varnish

Tags: varnish

I'm running Amazon Linux.

I originally installed Varnish 3 on this box, but have now installed Varnish 4.

```
sudo varnishd -a 0.0.0.0:80 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

...works just fine to start Varnish 4, and

```
pkill varnishd
```

...works fine to kill it.

But

```
service varnish stop
```

appears to control Varnish 3, and not Varnish 4. I'm very confused!

Why is this? What can I do to help this box forget about Varnish 3?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the service script even has a 'stop' command?

Comment: service just passes the command to the /etc/init.d/varnish script. Perhaps that script was not updated upon upgrade. What method did you use to upgrade?

Comment: @mdpc It does! `service varnish start` will start a phantom version of Varnish 3 somewhere; `service varnish stop` will stop it.

Comment: @Bin - yum install; so perhaps I ought to go and take a look at that script?

Comment: @jamescridland Yes, also check there is no /etc/init.d/varnish4 script there or anything similar.

Comment: @bin Well, that script has in it... `exec="/usr/sbin/varnishd"` which is exactly the same as I'm running (above). There isn't another varnishd on my system. Hmm.

Comment: `rpm -qa | grep arnish` for check varnish version(s) installed in your aws linux instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you'd like to use `service` to stop `Varnish`, you should also use same `service` to start `Varnish` as well, and not running it manually like you do.

if you need to update your script, use either `whereis` or `which` to find where your binary is, then make sure that your init script points to same place as what you found:

```
# grep ^exec /etc/init.d/varnish
exec="/usr/sbin/varnishd"
#
```

and that's all assuming you're using RHEL6, as for RHEL7 `Varnish` comes with `systemd` script:

```
$ rpm -q varnish
varnish-4.0.3-3.el7.x86_64
$ grep ^ExecStart /usr/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service 
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/varnishd -C -f $VARNISH_VCL_CONF
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd \
$
```

also, unless there is an actual need, i don't think it's good idea to have both of them installed on same system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the varnish init script and make sure it points to the correct server binary and pid file that are actually used by varnish 4.